# jQuery append method inserting text rather than HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I want append an input text in my html page. I use JQuery to do that.

My JQuery script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".reply").click(function(){
      var tempat=$(this).parent().parent().next(".komentar-balasan");
      console.log(tempat[0]);
      var html=
      tempat[0].append('<input type="text"></input>');
    });
  });
```

And the HTML :

```
 <div class="isi">
    <div class="like-comment">
     <div class="kotak"></div>
     <div class="kotak-jumlah">
     </div>
     <div class="kotak"><button class="reply"></button></div>
   </div><div class="komentar-balasan"></div>
```

[The Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/papbou5h/1/)

I Don't know why, but instead of displayed the input text box. The browser just display `<input type="text"></input>`. It's like the browser didn't recognize the HTML code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because `tempat[0]` is accessing the underlying DOM node rather than the jQuery wrapper.  It works fine if you omit the array access and just call `append` on `tempat`.

You don't need it here but the right way to get a jQuery wrapped element of a jQuery selector list is to use [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: I just realize because in the last I use next() method. because in the beginning, I was use parent() only. So it returned many objects. Btw, thanks it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you aren't calling the `append` element on a jQuery object (which treats strings as HTML), but instead on a native DOM element. The experimental [`ParentNode#append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) method treats strings as text, so you are seeing text.

If you omit the `[0]` before calling `append`, your code runs perfectly:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#post-komentar").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).siblings('.editor-komentar').val());
  });
  $(".reply").click(function() {
    var tempat = $(this).parent().parent().next(".komentar-balasan");
    console.log(tempat[0]);
    var html =
      tempat.append('<input type="text"></input>');
  });
});
```

```css
.reply {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="isi">
  <div class="like-comment">
    <div class="kotak">&lt;</div>
    <div class="kotak-jumlah">
    </div>
    <div class="kotak"><button class="reply"></button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="komentar-balasan"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hello,

Check if this is what you need:

You need to create an element and only then add it.

Here is an example:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".reply").click(function(){
          var tempat=$(this).parent().parent().next(".komentar-balasan");
          console.log(tempat[0]);
          var newEl = document.createElement('input');
          newEl.type = "text";
          tempat.append(newEl);
        });
      });
```

I hope I have helped!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the [0]. You are dereferencing your jQuery object by doing that.

This works: `tempat.append('<input type="text"></input>');`